# Why am I getting this error in the GridView's Pagination Functionality?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET Webforms developer and I am working on an example to demonstrate all the functionalities of GridView control. I am trying to develop a GridView with CRUD and Pagination functionalities. All the functionalities are working find except the pagination.

First of all, I am having the following GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                OnRowCommand="gvItems_RowCommand" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"
                OnPageIndexChanging="gvItems_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="detail" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button"
                        Text="Detail" HeaderText="Detailed View">
                        <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button"
                        Text="Edit" HeaderText="Edit Record">
                        <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="deleteRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info"
                        ButtonType="Button" Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete Record">
                        <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
</Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

before, in the code-behind, I had the following code and the pagination was working very well:

```
protected void gvItems_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("detail"))
        {
            Items item = new Items();
            dvItems.DataSource = item.getData();
            dvItems.DataBind();
....
        }
        else if (e.CommandName.Equals("editRecord"))
        {
            bindDdlItemTypeNew();
            bindDdlStatusNew();
            GridViewRow gvrow = gvItems.Rows[index];
            lblID.Text = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;
            ........

        }
        else if (e.CommandName.Equals("deleteRecord"))
        {
            int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.DataKeys[index].Value);
            hfId.Value = itemId.ToString();
            ...
        }
    }
```

Now, I have this code where I instantiate the ItemID variable at the beginning of the method and because of that I am getting an error as shown in the snapshot below:

```
protected void gvItems_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.DataKeys[index].Value);
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("detail"))
        {
            Items item = new Items();
            //int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.DataKeys[index].Value);
            item.ID = itemId;
            dvItems.DataSource = item.getData(item);
            dvItems.DataBind();
            ...
        }
        else if (e.CommandName.Equals("editRecord"))
        {
            bindDdlItemTypeNew();
            bindDdlStatusNew();
            GridViewRow gvrow = gvItems.Rows[index];
            lblID.Text = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;
            ...

        }
        else if (e.CommandName.Equals("deleteRecord"))
        {
            //int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(gvItems.DataKeys[index].Value);
            hfId.Value = itemId.ToString();
            ...
        }
    }
```

And here is the error:

[image]

**Could you please explain to me why I am getting this type of error?**

Comment: Can you include code for `PageIndexChanging` handler as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use e.CommandArgument, you need to set CommandArgument in the button. This code doesn't set CommandArgument:

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="detail" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button"
   Text="Detail" HeaderText="Detailed View">
   <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>
</asp:ButtonField>
```

You can set CommandArgument using #Eval to get the ID for the current row:

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="detail" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' ...
```

...in which case you wouldn't need to look it up in the DataKeys.